# iOS7 Webapp Spash Screen / Startup Image not rendering properly

Tags: ios, hyperlink, meta-tags, iphone-web-app

The startup / spashscreen images renders on load properly with transparent background on initial launch of the webapp from home screen; however, after about .5-1 second after the initial load the status bar turns white (the status bar text color stays white as well) and pushs the startup image down the height of the status bar. After the webapp loads it goes back to transparent as well.

I don't have enough rep to post picture so i have to post links.

[inital start up before it push down](https://lifedup.com/img1.PNG)

[After load with white bar at the top](https://lifedup.com/img2.PNG)

Thus it makes a white bar across the top of the start up screen.

**Does anyone know how to fix this issue of the status bar turning white or a way to hide it completely on start up?**

I'm using iOS7.1 on a sprint iPhone 4s if that makes a difference.  Here is also the meta / link calls I'm making.

```
<!--apple make full screen / hide url bar in browser / no zoom / full size-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no; minimal-ui">
<!--apple lauch from homescreen-->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<!--other lauch from homescreen-->
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<!--apple lauch from homescreen makes status bar transparent w/white text-->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
<!--apple lauch from title to make different from site title-->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Timekeeping">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../marton/icons/marton_timekeeping_512.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="../marton/icons/marton_timekeeping_76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="../marton/icons/marton_timekeeping_120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="../marton/icons/marton_timekeeping_152.png">
<!-- Startup images -->
<!-- iOS 6 & 7 iPad (retina, portrait) -->
<link href="../marton/startup/apple-touch-startup-image-1536x2008.png"media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)and (orientation: portrait)and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iOS 6 & 7 iPad (retina, landscape) -->
<link href="../marton/startup/apple-touch-startup-image-1496x2048.png"media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)and (orientation: landscape)and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iOS 6 iPad (portrait) -->
<link href="../marton/startup/apple-touch-startup-image-768x1004.png"media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)and (orientation: portrait)and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)"rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iOS 6 iPad (landscape) -->
<link href="../marton/startup/apple-touch-startup-image-748x1024.png"media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)and (orientation: landscape)and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)"rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iOS 6 & 7 iPhone 5 -->
<link href="../marton/startup/apple-touch-startup-image-640x1096.png"media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px)and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iOS 6 & 7 iPhone (retina) -->
<link href="../marton/startup/apple-touch-startup-image-640x920.png"media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px)and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iOS 6 iPhone -->
<link href="../marton/startup/apple-touch-startup-image-320x460.png"media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px)and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)"rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- other iPhone -->
<link href="../marton/startup/apple-touch-startup-image-320x460.png"rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```